# Get value in placeholder array in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a error with while_loop, when I try to read a value in a placeholder.

The need package:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# Start TensorFlow InteractiveSession
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# We define the input variable set to the problem 
input1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,100], name='input1') 

# Define the variable to traing 
L = tf.Variable(np.identity(100, dtype='float32'), trainable=False)
i0 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
```

We use a function to definition of the body, or the lambda function to the condition. This is indiferent...

But I have a problem, because I want get the values of input1 at some position. Y try the used of eval, i0.eval() but this don't work.

```
def body(i0,L,input1):
    N_valu = input1[:,i0] # Here is the error... 
    L = L+N_valu*tf.matmul(tf.transpose(L),L)
    i0 = tf.add(i0,1)
    return i0,L,input1

condition = lambda i0,L,input1: i0 < 100

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
i00,L0,input10 = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [i0,L,input1])

N1 = np.array(range(0,100)).reshape([1,100])

feed_dict={input1:N1, i0:0}
Lprueba = L0.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
print(i00.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict))
```

Some help?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: I solve this problem with `tf.gather`, the problem was the slices. Thank!!

Comment: In tensorflow 1.1, `tf.Tensor.__getitem__` operator can take the tensor.